# Cannot resolve method session.getDefaultInstance()

Tags: android, jakarta-mail

I am trying to write automailsending code. Here, I am getting an error: Cannot resolve method 'getDefaultInstance(java.util.Properties, com.example.automailsendinganika.Sender)' in this line : session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, this);

this is my Sender class:

---

```
class Sender  extends javax.mail.Authenticator {

    private String mailhost = "smtp.gmail.com";
    private String user;
    private String password;
    private Session session;

    static {
        Security.addProvider(new com.provider.JSSEProvider());
    }

    public Sender(String user, String password) {
        this.user = user;
        this.password = password;

        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.setProperty("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
        props.setProperty("mail.host", mailhost);
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class",
                "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false");
        props.setProperty("mail.smtp.quitwait", "false");

        session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, this);
    }

    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
        return new PasswordAuthentication(user, password);
    }

    public synchronized void sendMail(String subject, String body, String sender, String recipients) throws Exception {
        try{
            MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
            DataHandler handler = new DataHandler(new ByteArrayDataSource(body.getBytes(), "text/plain"));
            message.setSender(new InternetAddress(sender));
            message.setSubject(subject);
            message.setDataHandler(handler);
            if (recipients.indexOf(',') > 0)
                message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse(recipients));
            else
                message.setRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(recipients));
            Transport.send(message);
            Log.e("SEND ","SEND");
        }catch(Exception e){
            Log.e("ERROR ","ERROR");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public class ByteArrayDataSource implements DataSource {
        private byte[] data;
        private String type;

        public ByteArrayDataSource(byte[] data, String type) {
            super();
            this.data = data;
            this.type = type;
        }

        public ByteArrayDataSource(byte[] data) {
            super();
            this.data = data;
        }

        public void setType(String type) {
            this.type = type;
        }

        public String getContentType() {
            if (type == null)
                return "application/octet-stream";
            else
                return type;
        }

        public InputStream getInputStream() throws IOException {
            return new ByteArrayInputStream(data);
        }

        public String getName() {
            return "ByteArrayDataSource";
        }

        public OutputStream getOutputStream() throws IOException {
            throw new IOException("Not Supported");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try using "Session.getInstance(props, this);" instead of what you are using. Default instance is something different.

Comment: I tried with "Session.getInstance(props, this);" still I'm getting error. the error is: Cannot resolve method 'getInstance(java.util.Properties, com.example.automailsendinganika.Sender)'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have just got the problem. I used

> import android.se.omapi.Session;
>   instead of
>   "import javax.mail.Session;"